# Editing ini file using python "ConfigParser" will replace all ini entries to lower keys

Tags: python, configparser

The code snippet below can edit an ini file, but will replace all ini entries to lower case:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("test.ini")
config.set("GENERAL", "OptionEntry4", "100")
with open("test.ini", 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

**ini file before edit:**

**[GENERAL]**

OptionEntry1 = 10

OptionEntry2 = 20

OptionEntry3 = 30

OptionEntry4 = 40

OptionEntry5 = 50

**ini file after edit:**

**[GENERAL]**

optionentry1 = 10

optionentry2 = 20

optionentry3 = 30

optionentry4 = 100

optionentry5 = 50

Answer (score 3):

according to the documentation : "All option names are passed through the optionxform() method. Its default implementation converts option names to lower case."

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
config.read("test.ini")
config.set("GENERAL", "OptionEntry4", "100")
with open("test.ini", 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Read the doc: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.optionxform